# React useState not setting initialValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

useState doesn't seem to be able to set an initial value properly.

I have a component that starts something like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useState("abc")

  console.log(currentUser)

  return(
    <div>{currentUser}</div>
  )
};
```

However, it keeps logging "undefined" no matter what value I set as the initial state.

Similarly, whenever I try to call setCurrentUser, I get a TypeError that "setCurrentUser" is not a function.

Can anyone help diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```
const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState("ABC")
```

not

```
const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useState("ABC") // wrong syntax, see above
```

See [the new docs on `useState`](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState) for a better, direct, explanation.

Comment: lol oops, not sure how I missed that. Thank you!